# Virtuoso set up troubleshooting

Tags: php, rdf, semantic-web, virtuoso

I have been following [general set up instructions for Virtuoso](https://github.com/bio2rdf/bio2rdf-scripts/wiki/Developers) from the [Bio2RDF project](http://bio2rdf.org/).

My `rdfloader.php` exits with no issues (after much headache), but I'm not convinced any data was actually pushed, and if a "graph" has been named / set up to inherit any of that data. Here is the output of my `rdfloader.php` script (which to me indicates a lack of an error status):

execution command:

```
sudo php rdfload.php i=default d=/Users/username/php-lib/ f=*.nt
```

output:

```
ld_dir('/Users/lillian.rosa/php-lib/','*.nt','test');rdf_loader_run();checkpoint;
```

When I go to run basic queries on the RDF graph, however, NOTHING works. This brings me to question if any of my data in my `.nt` file was actually loaded.

How can I troubleshoot this situation? The docs on [`http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/`](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/) haven't been so helpful.

Comment: The `output` you show here looks like iSQL commands to load the data, not their result...  Perhaps try some product-specific resources like the [Bio2RDF forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bio2rdf), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), or the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php)?  (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Comment: Knowing more about what you've done will likely help -- especially what docs you found not to be so helpful, and how this was so...

Comment: @areyoujokingme any update on this? I am stuck with same issue!